# Null reference error in trigger on required field

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I have this trigger that changes the Name of a record based on a custom `title__c` field:

```
trigger assignDegreeName on Degree__c (before insert) {
    /**
    Variables
    **/
    integer maxSize = 80;    

    /**
    Assign Name to new Degree
    **/
    for (Degree__c newDegree: Trigger.New) {
        string degreeName = newDegree.title__c;
        if (degreeName.length() > maxSize) {
            degreeName = degreeName.substring(0, maxSize);
        }

        newDegree.Name = degreeName;
    }
}
```

`title__c` is a required field, and I know that the endpoints we use to create Degrees will send an empty string, not null, for title anyways. So it should never be null and even if it is, it shouldn't get to this point in the trigger without failing in the first place because of the requirements.

Yet, I always get the error response `attempt to de-reference a Null object` on row `400` when I hit the api endpoint that uploads a bunch of degrees at once.

What could possibly be Null in this trigger?

Comment: Is this the only detail in the exception? What are other details which suggests the source of the exception? The only possible value that could throw that exception here seems to be `degreeName`. What do you see when you log a system.debug on `newDegree.title__c`, does it contain a `null` value at all?

Comment: No, and it never should because it's a string, strings get casted as `''` not null...

Comment: No. `''` and `null` are different. `''` is an empty string with size = 0. Strings don't get casted to `''` if the value is `null`.

Comment: So turns out, title__c gets set as `"\u0646\u0638\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0644\u0648\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0627\u0633\u0648\u0628\u064a\u0629"` and that is what is being considered `null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never assume field values are not null, even those which are required. It is bad practice, and will throw `NullPointerException` rather than `DmlException` when the field is provided blank. It will screw with your unit tests, integrations, etc. Especially on insert triggers.

Your trigger will not see a difference between `null` and `''`.  Other best practices include **moving your logic to an `Apex Class`**. You should have a method that looks something like:

```
public with sharing class DegreeService
{
    public static void truncateTitles(List<Degree__c> records)
    {
        for (Degree__c record : records) truncateTitle(record);
    }
    public static void truncateTitle(Degree__c record)
    {
        if (record.Title__c == null) return;

        // now run your logic
    }
}
```